# Docker PostgreSQL удаленный доступ

Tags: postgresql

Прошу помощи.

На удаленной машине в докер контейнере крутится PostgreSQL 13. Никак не могу получить доступ к нему удаленно, ошибка  `no pg_hba.conf entry for host` бла бла, ssl выключен.

С локальной машины по имени хоста localhost или 127.0.0.1 все превосходно. Но если локально указываю уже конкретный IP текущего сервера 192.168.1.102 - вышеозначенная ошибка. И с любой удаленной машины она же

`postgresql.conf`

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

`pg_hba.conf`

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
#host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32           trust
host     all             all             all                    trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host     all             all             ::1/128                trust
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     trust
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 trust

host all all all md5
```

помогите, плиз

Comment: reload (или рестарт) базы делали после правки hba?

Comment: весь контейнер рестартую конечно же

Comment: покажите результат `select * from pg_hba_file_rules where type = 'host' and address = 'all';`

Comment: ````postgres=# select * from pg_hba_file_rules where type = 'host' and address = 'all';
 line_number | type | database | user_name | address | netmask | auth_method | options | error
-------------+------+----------+-----------+---------+---------+-------------+---------+-------
          91 | host | {all}    | {all}     | all     |         | trust       |         |
          99 | host | {all}    | {all}     | all     |         | md5         |         |
(2 rows)````

Comment: Вы смогли решить эту проблему ? У меня такая же ситуация

Comment: @vip2ip Нет, я тогда плюнул и вообще ушел от Докера в сторону виртуальной машины, которая прозрачна по взаимодействию и настройкам и полностью удовлетворяет моим потребностям.